# Avoid dropdown icon on newline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following navbar in Bootstrap:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="dropdow-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i><span class="header-text"> Download PDF </span><span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="pdf">
            <li><a href="https://github.com/raphink/CV/blob/master/RaphaelPinson_en.pdf?raw=true">English</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://github.com/raphink/CV/blob/master/RaphaelPinson_fr.pdf?raw=true">Français</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When viewed on a mobile device, if I click on the Dropdown and I have more than one link in the navbar, the whole dropdown+menu go on a new line.

On desktop:

[image: Desktop screenshot]

On mobile:

[image: Mobile screenshot]

How can I avoid that, and make sure the icon stays on the top line, however large the dropdown menu is?

Comment: The full interface demonstrating the problematic behavior is http://cv.raphink.info/, viewed on a mobile when clicking one of the two dropdown links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start fixing your code by setting the following css:

```
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  left: 0;
}
```

I changed the position to `absolute` from `static` and set `left: 0;` for the dropdown menu to align to the left of it's parent which is where you click to open the dropdown menu. Also removed the `background-color: transparent;` because otherwise the dropdown won't have a `background-color` and won't be really visible on top of other elements on the page.

Further down the road you would probably want to set the padding or some other style attribute to your `<li>` tags for them to expand to the full height of the navbar. This way your dropdown will start correctly from the navbar. Or you can play with margins etc.

Hopefully this get's you to the right direction and you can set the rest of what you want/need by yourself.

Comment: Thank you. It actually already does what I want with `.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  left: 0;
}`

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I ended up adapting @thepio's answer:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 48px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

I used a `fixed` position to allow displaying the menu in full width, set `top` to 48px to be under the toggle button and set the `border-top` and `box-shadow` to match the `navbar-default` style. Finally, I set the width to `100vw` to have a fullscreen width of the menu:

[image: Full width]